# Getting gzip compression to work on my server (modules?)

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd, httpd.conf, gzip

I have copied the `htaccess` file from [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess#L153) into my `httpd.conf` file and restarted Apache, but for some reason, gzip compression is still not working:

[image]

I have tested to see if the modules referenced in this boilerplate code are loaded, and they seem to be, but perhaps with different names. Do I need to modify the module names so that the code works, or could the problem be elsewhere?

Modules:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the `mod_filter` module, so I added this to my `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
```